# Grep for a range of numbers

Tags: text-processing, awk, grep, bioinformatics

I have a .txt file with multiple lines that gives amino acid and residue data. The data looks like this:

```
ARG262-Side ASP368-Side 140,83%
ARG95-Side GLU107-Side 103,73%
ARG474-Side VAL468-Main 94,93%
PHE169-Main ALA190-Main 94,63%
THR205-Side ASP203-Side 94,07%
ILE299-Main LYS249-Main 94%
LEU354-Main LYS365-Main 93,6%
ARG346-Side GLU263-Side 93,57%
LEU301-Main ALA247-Main 93,43%
ALA190-Main PHE169-Main 93,37%
SER252-Side ASP296-Side 93,1%
TYR424-Side ASN446-Main 93%
```

I can roughly say that the numbers indicate residues and the letters indicate aminoacids. So, both in the first and second field of each line, the part before the `-` consists of an aminoacid identifier and a residue value. I want to print only lines where the see residue value lies in a certain range, regardless of amino acid, and regardless of whether the first or second field matches the criterion.

For example, from the above input file, I want to extract data that contains only residues between **300-425**. In this case, my output should look like this:

```
ARG262-Side ASP368-Side 140,83%
LEU354-Main LYS365-Main 93,6%
ARG346-Side GLU263-Side 93,57%
LEU301-Main ALA247-Main 93,43%
TYR424-Side ASN446-Main 93%
```

I tried using the `grep` command for this, but I wasn't very successful. Is there a command I can use other than `grep`?

Comment: Please edit your question and include what you already tried, so that answerers don't suggest the same commands.

Comment: you could say that specific field info; https://www.genome.jp/kegg/catalog/codes1.html

Comment: A general remark to notice: If you deal with files on Linux that have been created/modified on a Windows machine, be aware that these OSs use different end-of-line indicators. If you experience unexpected output behaviour, you may have to run the file through `dos2unix` before processing.

Comment: Actually, I downloaded the Ubuntu console to my computer and working on Windows. But if I switch to Linux completely in the future, I will keep this in mind. Thank you so much @AdminBee. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tools that mainly deal with regular expressions are notoriously bad at dealing with numbers.  In this case, I would suggest using something like `awk` instead of `grep`:

```
$ awk '{ r1 = substr($1,4,3); r2 = substr($2,4,3) } (r1 >= 300 && r1 <= 425) || (r2 >= 300 && r2 <= 425)' file
ARG262-Side ASP368-Side 140,83%
LEU354-Main LYS365-Main 93,6%
ARG346-Side GLU263-Side 93,57%
LEU301-Main ALA247-Main 93,43%
TYR424-Side ASN446-Main 93%
```

The `awk` code extracts the tree characters, starting at offset four, from the first two whitespace-delimited fields on each line, and calls these `r1` and `r2`.  I'm using `substr()` to extract the numbers at fixed positions in the data of the fields, but you could also just delete all non-digits, if you're certain that the only digits are the ones that you're interested in. You would do that with

```
r1 = $1; gsub("[^[:digit:]]", "", r1)
```

and similarly for `r2` using `$2`.

If the condition at the end is true, the current line would be printed.

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked. But I do not fully understand what the parameters you give to r values mean.
r1 = substr ($ 1,4,3); r2 = substr ($ 2,4,3)
Would you please explain it a little bit more?

Comment: The `substr()` command extracts a part of the string mentioned as first argument, starting at the character nr. stated in the second argument, and with a length as per the third argument. So, `r1 = substr($1, 4, 3)` assigns to `r1` that part of the first field (`$1`) that starts at the 4th character (the first digit) and is three characters (=digits in this case) long. Try `man awk`, it is should be well-documented.

Comment: I got it now, thank you very much. :)

Comment: Hello again. I tried to run this code:

$ awk '{ r1 = substr($1,4,3); r2 = substr($2,4,3) } (r1 >= 206 && r1 <= 212 || (r2 >= 206 && r2 <= 212)' deneme.dat

But I got an error like this:

awk: cmd. line:2: { r1 = substr($1,4,3); r2 = substr($2,4,3) } (r1 >= 206 && r1 <= 212 || (r2 >= 206 && r2 <= 212)
awk: cmd. line:2:            ^ unexpected newline or end of string

I checked my file but could not find what caused the error. Do you have any idea?

Comment: @DermanBasturk Yes, you seem to be missing a `)`, just before `||`.

Comment: :'D Thanks a lot.

Comment: I have one last question : 

Some of my resid values are 2 digits. For example:

THR89-Side ALA91Main 18.2
THR89-Main VAL109-Main 12,37

When I wrote (r1> = 89 && r1 <= 212) in code, it didn't find anything. I am aware that the problem is because we set the number of digits to 3 in the "substr" command, but I don't know how to fix it. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: @DermanBasturk add `+ 0` after each `substr()` call, so, for `r1` you'd have `r1 = substr(...) + 0`.  This will force `awk` to interpret the string as a number.  If there are non-digits at the end of the string, these will simply be discarded.

Comment: Thank you very much, you are a hero. :D

Answer (score 6):

Using `awk`:

```
awk -F'(^| )...|-' '$2>300 && $2<425 || $4>300 && $4<425' infile
```

here, we set the field seperator to:

- start of line followed by 3 characters `^...`, or
- a space followed by 3 characters  `...`, or
- a hyphen character

then based on these, column#2 and column#4 would be the residues of the aminoacids and so we checks if that's between given range.

Comment: You could also use `[^[:digit:]]+` as `FS` and check `$2` and `$3`.

Comment: @Kusalananda ah, yes, that's good one and assuming there is no any digits after `-` in first column then it will mess and some would be in `$2` and `$3` and some in `$2` and `$4`.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```bsh
grep -E '[^0-9](3[0-9][0-9]|4[01][0-9]|42[0-5])-' file`
```

- `-E` enables extended regular expressions (where you don't need to backslash parentheses and pipe)
- `[^0-9](` -- a non-digit, followed by

  - `3[0-9][0-9]|` a number between 300 and 399, or
  - `4[01][0-9]|` a number between 400 and 419, or
  - `42[0-5]` a number between 420 and 425
- `)-` followed by a hyphen

Providing the non-digit requirement means you don't match `ABC1234-Something`

Answer (score 0):

```
grep -E "(^[[:upper:]]{3}(3[0-9]{2}|4([0-1][0-9]|2[0-5]))|\b[[:upper:]]{3}(3[0-9]{2}|4([0-1][0-9]|2[0-5])))" sample.txt
```

`grep -E` with extended regular expression.

`^[[:upper:]]{3}` : If the line start with three upper alphabetic character

`3[0-9]{2}` : Match any sequence of digit greater or equal to 300

`|` : or

`4([0-1][0-9]|2[0-5])` : between 400 and 425.

`|` : Or (here look at the second column)

`\b` : The world is boundaries (There is a space)

`[[:upper:]]{3}(3[0-9]{2}|4([0-1][0-9]|2[0-5]))` : The same as in the first path.